# Shows discord bot.py missing permissions

Tags: python, discord.py

So I want to make that my bot could print what is the missing permissions for certain actions.
Here's my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error): #error commands handler
if isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingPermissions):
    await ctx.send("Bot didn\'t has such a permissions")
    #this line gonna print what are the missing permissions

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.bot_has_permissions(read_messages = True, manage_messages = True, read_message_history = 
True)
async def purge(ctx, amount : int): #clear amount of messages
    #do something
```

So how do I print the missing permissions?

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20botmissingpermissions#discord.ext.commands.BotMissingPermissions.missing_perms

I haven't tried it but from the docs I'd assume you get the information which permissions are missing with `error.missing_perms`

Comment: could you try it and show me the code, please? I'm kinda confused right now

Comment: uhh nvm, the only thing I confused how do I put the perms inside `missing_perms`, I already tried `read_messages`, `manage_message`, `read_message_history`, but it doesn't work.  hmmm...

Comment: oh nvm, I already found it, thanks a lot btw :)

Answer (score 1):

So this code gonna print all the required permissions **not** only permission that bot doesn't have, but I think it's still pretty nice

```
 @bot.event
 async def on_command_error(ctx, error): #error commands handler
 if isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingPermissions):
    await ctx.send("Bot didn\'t has such a permissions")
    await.ctx.send(f'{commands.BotMissingPermissions(["read_message", 
    "manage_messages", "read_message_history"])}') #this line gonna print what 
    are the required permissions

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.bot_has_permissions(read_messages = True, manage_messages = True, 
read_message_history = True)
async def purge(ctx, amount : int): #clear amount of messages
    #do something
```